# Complex arithmetic in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I have a table as follows:

```
product | quantity | price | gift | giftprice
--------|----------|-------|------|----------
1       | 2        | 9.99  | 0    | 4.99
2       | 3        | 3.50  | 1    | 2.25
3       | 1        | 4.75  | 1    | 1.50
```

What I'd like to have an SQL query that will give me a figure that gives me the sum of all the records with quantity multiplied by price with the giftprice being added to the price before multiplication only if the 'gift' field is set to 1.

Pseudocode

```
foreach(record){
   if(gift == 1){ linetotal = (price + giftprice) * quantity; }
   else { linetotal = price * quantity; }
   total = total + linetotal;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I didn't think it it was good practice to do arithmetic in SQL

Comment: @harold I think it depends on the circumstances. In this case pulling all the records from the database then performing the calculations would be a lot slower than asking the SQL server to do the calculations. I think! Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just do:

```
SELECT product, (price + gift * giftprice) * quantity AS total
FROM theTable
```

Since nothing will be added if `gift = 0`.

Comment: That makes so much sense. Can't see the wood for the trees sometimes! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUM( (price + giftprice*gift) * quantity)
       AS total
FROM yourTable
;
```